# Aligning thick hlines and vlines with tabularray

Tags: tabularray

I wrote a table like in the following MWE, using `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        hlines,
        vlines,
        hline{1,2,Z}={2pt},
        vline{1,2,Z}={2pt},
        hline{3}={1}{2pt},
        vline{3}={1}{2pt}
    }
 Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
 Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
 Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

with the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the thick horizontal and vertical lines aren't aligned with the thin ones. I would want the thin lines to come out of the center of the thick lines. How do I do that?

Comment: This is a known limitation of `tabularray`, see https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/350.

Answer (score 4):

For information, here is a way to have to reach your goal with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,rules/width=2pt]
   Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
   Epsilon & \Block{2-2}{} Zeta & Eta \\
   Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\CodeAfter
   \tikz \draw (3-|2) -- (3-|4) ; 
   \tikz \draw (2-|3) -- (4-|3) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]